# display:none and visibility:hidden returns white space-css

Tags: css

Guys am working in service now. I just trying to remove header banner on page
[image]

when I hide the header banner its returning the white space.
[image]
I have tried with 
display:none/visibility:hidden and absolute positioning also still am unable to remove the white space.

css code:

```
.navpage-header{
display:none;
position:absolute;
}
```

Am unable to create a snippet here because its just a servicenow page.

Guys please help me on this I got struck for past 10days in this requirement and I did not get any solution.

Please Advice!!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide some css code so we can have a look at it

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Please use working code to expose your problem. Using images and expecting us to figure out the problem for you is not going to work. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code. thansk

Comment: @downvoter why did you downvote my question?may I know the reason?

Comment: Its likely a fixed or absolute positioned header with the content pushed out of the way with margin or padding.

Comment: @krish - your question is too broad. We only see to images but no code. We need some code to reproduce the issue. We need to see how the site is build and which CSS styles are active. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @krish Just add your html and css what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin-top of the form element or padding of the body.

```
body {
  padding-top: 0;
}

form {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```